# как через telebot сделать чтобы текст копировался по нажатию

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть вот такой код задача сделать так чтобы при выводе текста. из переменной fraze он копировался поесть просто нажал на него и тебе вылетает табличка

> текст успешно скопирован

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(frase), parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)`

Answer (score 2):

На вопрос дан частичный ответ в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713920/how-to-make-that-when-you-click-on-the-text-it-was-copied-pytelegrambotapi

Если вы используете `parse_mode=MARKDOWN`, то можете сделать так:

```
frase = 12345
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'`{frase}`', parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

Если вы используете `parse_mode=HTML`, то можете сделать так:

```
frase = 12345
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<code>{frase}</code>', parse_mode=HTML)
```

Это указано в технической документации API Telegram: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options